# Attribute Error: function has no attribute 'desc'

Tags: python, function, object, attributeerror

I am trying out the code from the book:  Beginning Robotics with Raspberry Pi and Arduino: Using Python and OpenCV.  In the first chapter, the author has us type in a code to simulate controlling a robot.  In python, a file is created called robot_sample_class.py and the code is:

```
class Robot(): 
"""
    A simple robot class
    This multi-line comment is a good place
    to provide a description of what the class
    is.
    """

    # define the initiating function.
    # speed = value between 0 and 255
    # duration = value in milliseconds
    def __init__(self, name, desc, color, owner,
                speed = 125, duration = 100):
            # initiates our robot
        self.name = name
        self.desc = desc
        self.color = color
        self.owner = owner
        self.speed = speed
        self.duration = duration

    def drive_forward(self):
        # simulates driving forward
        print(self.name.title() + " is driving" +
                " forward " + str(self.duration) +
                " milliseconds")

    def drive_backward(self):
        # simulates driving backward
        print(self.name.title() + " is driving" +
                " backward " + str(self.duration) +
                " milliseconds")

    def turn_left(self):
        # simulates turning left
        print(self.name.title() + " is turning " +
                " right " + str(self.duration) +
                " milliseconds")

    def turn_right(self):
        # simulates turning right
        print(self.name.title() + " is turning " +
                " left " + str(self.duration) +
                " milliseconds")

    def set_speed(self, speed):
        # sets the speed of the motors
        self.speed = speed
        print("the motor speed is now " +
                str(self.speed))

    def set_duration(self, duration):
        # sets duration of travel
        self. duration = duration
        print("the duration is now " +
                str(self.duration))'
```

Then, I create a file called robot_sample.py and here is the code:

```
import robot_sample_class

def my_robot(): Robot("Nomad", "Autonomous rover","black", "Cecil")

print("My robot is a " + my_robot.desc + " called " + my_robot.name)

my_robot.drive_forward()
my_robot.drive_backward()
my_robot.turn_left()
my_robot.turn_right()
my_robot.set_speed(255)
my_robot.set_duration(1000)
```

When I run the robot_sample.py, I get an error message:  print("My robot is a " + my_robot.desc + " called " + my_robot.name).  AttributeError: function object has no attribute 'desc'.

I don't understand why the function does not have the attribute 'desc', when it is defined as "Autonomous rover".

Comment: try `my_robot = Robot(...)` and then `my_robot.desc` should be available

Comment: Thanks, that was what I had before, but it would bring up the error:  NameError: name 'Robot' is not defined.  So, if I change it to your suggestion, I just get a new error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to import class `Robot` from your module. Second, you should instantiate it (create a variable of this class). After that you can use it:

```
from robot_sample_class import Robot

my_robot = Robot("Nomad", "Autonomous rover","black", "Luke Periard")

print("My robot is a " + my_robot.desc + " called " + my_robot.name)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like the book was missing that line. It works now, python replies with "My robot is an autonomous rover called Nomad".  But now it has a new error: AttributeError: 'Robot' object has no atrribute 'drive_forward'.  I think I can figure this one out though...